# How to symlink with a Salt state?

Tags: salt-stack

Currently, I am using 2 folders to store the data.

```
/var/data : mongodb
/srv/data : redis
```

I have unify both the directories. I have to switch to `/srv/data`.

My question is, I have to create a salt state to create unix link `/srv/data/mongodb -> /var/data/mongodb` . So that data won't move.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.symlink

```yaml
/srv/data/mongodb:
  file.symlink:
    - target: /var/data/mongodb
```